# Minimize a Quadratic Cost Function on the Unit Simplex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

How can I compute
$$ \min_{x \in \Delta_n} \frac{1}{2}\lVert Bx\rVert^2 + x^tAy$$
with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in \mathbb{R}^m, A_{m \times n}$, $B_{n \times n}$ where $\Delta_n$ is the unit simplex
$$\Delta_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ | \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1\}$$
Are there standard algorithms for computing it?

Comment: This is known as [quadratic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming). The Wikipedia page lists a number of solution methods.

Comment: But how do I write the condition $e^tx = 1$ in terms of $Ax \leq b$ in this case?

Comment: The definition given in Wikipedia is slightly incomplete. In quadratic programming one allows both linear inequality constraints, $Ax\le b$, and linear equality constraints, $Cx=d$. So the unit simplex can be defined as $-Ix\le0,e^Tx=1$.

Comment: And for the special case when $B$ is diagonal, it can be computed efficiently in $O(n \cdot \log n)$ time. If you are interested, I will write a full answer.

Comment: Wikipedia is not incomplete. One equality can be written as two inequality constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also solve this by [Projected Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method#Subgradient-projection_.26_bundle_methods) since the [Projection onto the Unit Simplex](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/blob/master/Optimization/BallProjection/BallProjection.pdf) is known.

The Code:

```
vX = pinv(mA) * vB;
    
mAy = mA.' * vY;
mAA = mA.' * mA;

for ii = 1:numIterations
    stepSize = stepSizeBase / sqrt(ii);
    vG = (mAA * vX) + mAy;
    vX = vX - (stepSize * vG);
    vX = ProjectSimplex(vX, simplexRadius, stopThr);
end

objVal = (0.5 * sum((mA * vX) .^ 2)) + (vX.' * mAy);

disp([' ']);
disp(['Projected Gradient Solution Summary']);
disp(['The Optimal Value Is Given By - ', num2str(objVal)]);
disp(['The Optimal Argument Is Given By - [ ', num2str(vX.'), ' ]']);
disp([' ']);
```

You can even accelerate this using [Nesterov / FISTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Fast_gradient_methods) to get really fast and efficient algorithm.

You can have the Simplex Projection function from  my [Ball Projection GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/Optimization/BallProjection).