# Minimize pure quadratic subject to linear equality constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

The problem to solve is

$\min_x \sum_i \sum_j C_{ij} x_i x_j$ $\,$ s.t. $\sum_i x_i = 1$.

for $C$ a symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix. Or equivalently

$\min_x x'Cx$ $\,$ s.t. $x'e = 1$.

This feels similar to a quadratic minimization onto the positive simplex (for a particular norm induced by C), although here the individual $x_i$ might take negative values. As already stated in [How can I minimize a quadratic on the unit simplex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231309/how-can-i-minimize-a-quadratic-on-the-unit-simplex) such problem can be solved with general quadratic programming methods, which also applies here. However, it seems that for this particular case a closed form solution can be found as

$x_i = \frac{\sum_j C_{ij}^{-1}}{\sum_k \sum_j C_{kj}^{-1}}$,

as stated (without proof) in the paper "When Networks Disagree: Ensemble Methods for Hybrid Neural Networks", section 4: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.32.3857

---

[image]

---

How can this result be obtained?

And furthermore, would still be possible to find a closed form solution if positivity constraints are enforced as $x \geq 0$, recovering the positive simplex problem but for a pure symmetric quadratic objective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Lagrange multipliers, $x$ is a solution of your problem if there is $\mu$ such that
$$
2Cx + \mu e =0, \ x^Te =1.
$$
Solving the first equation for $x$ gives
$$
x = -\frac\mu2 C^{-1}e.
$$
However, $x^Te=1$ is required, so
$$
\mu = -2 (e^TC^{-1}e)^{-1}.
$$
And we get 
$$
x= \frac{C^{-1}e}{e^TC^{-1}e}.
$$

Comment: Great! This correctly addresses my first question. What about the second one? Would still be possible to get a similar result with positivity constraints on the x?

Comment: @albarji No, with additional non-negativity constraints this is much harder to solve.