# Proximal operator of the function $w \mapsto \max_{i=1}^k a_i^Tw$, for fixed $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in \mathbb R^n$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming, proximal-operators

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_k \in \mathbb R^n$ and consider the convex function $F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ defined by $F(w) := \max_{i=1}^k a_i^\top w $.

> **Question.** What is the proximal operator of $F$ ? That is, for $\lambda > 0$, find an a closed-form formual for at $z=z_\lambda(w) \in \mathbb R^n$ which minimizes $\lambda F(z) + (1/2)\|z-w\|^2$.

### My attempt

$$
\min_z \lambda F(z) + (1/2)\|z-w\|^2 = \min_z \max_i \lambda a_i^\top z + (1/2)\|z-w\|^2\\
= \min_z \max_{q \in \Delta_{k-1}} \lambda q^\top Az + (1/2)\|z-w\|^2\\
= \max_{q \in \Delta_{k-1}} 
 \min_z \lambda q^\top Az + (1/2)\|z-w\|^2.
$$

The inner-most problem has explicity solution $z=w - \lambda A^\top q$. Thus, we would be done if we had a closed-form expression for $q$.

Comment: You get $\max_{q \in \Delta_{k-1}} \{\lambda q^TAw - 0.5 \lambda^2 q^T AA^T q  \}$. I cannot think of a closed-form solution. Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231309/minimize-a-quadratic-cost-function-on-the-unit-simplex).

Comment: Indeed, and that the objective in the above display is strongly convex if $A$ is full rank. Therefore sastifies a Kurdyka-Lojasiewicz inequality of exponent 1/2 around the optimal value of $q$. Therefore can be iteratively (like so https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1311138/168758) with linear convergence. This is perhaps one can get to closed-form solution.